# "Learn more" button on tags is broken in Chrome 30

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome Version 30.0.1599.10 dev. I was showing a friend how tags work when asking a question on Stack Overflow and typed in "php". When I clicked the "learn more" info link it did nothing. Is this a bug?

Comment: It works for me

Comment: Beta/dev versions of browsers are not supported. Works fine in Chrome 28. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: even on meta stackoverflow (sorry it doesn't do 'nothing', it closes the tag dropdown element)

Comment: Try with a supported browser.

Comment: thanks Mat, i don't have enough rep to accept or up vote.

Comment: There is `target="_blank"` on the link so most likely you have popup blocker installed that is blocking the link. Disable it and you'll have it working and opening in new tab.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome dev. Looks like it's a bug in Chrome, as I can fix the behaviour by doing something that should be a no-op. I'll poke at it a bit more to see if I can root out the cause, hopefully whatever's causing this won't make it into stable.

Comment: @Tim so it isn't some built-in popup blocker that just blocks anything with "target" attribute? These days with more and more users being fanatic about popup windows, I won't be surprised with such a feature.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Making a browser not respect the `target` attribute would be quite… dumb.

Comment: @TimStone FYI: Chrome 30 is now stable, and this issue is still present: [“Learn More” link on tags broken in latest Chrome stable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199611/197656)