# "Learn More" link on tags broken in latest Chrome stable

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, google-chrome

> **Note:** This is identical to [“Learn more” button on tags is broken in Chrome 30](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193736/197656), but that bug was declined because Chrome 30 was in dev. Chrome 30 has now been released, and still has this issue.

The "Learn More" link for tags is broken in the latest release of Google Chrome.

[image]

If I right-click and open in new tab, I get the tag's page, but just clicking doesn't work.

I'm using Chrome 30.0.15599.69, the latest stable release:
[image]

Comment: Confirmed, OSX 10.8.5. Worked fine before restarting, doesn't work after.

Comment: Confirmed, OSX 10.7.5, Chrome 30.0.1599.69. It's stopped working.

Comment: Confirmed, Win 7, 30.0.1599.69m. Looks like I had the same trouble with x.59m too, just never noticed it.

Comment: See also: http://meta.serverfault.com/q/5808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 12/04/2013 on Chrome 31.0.1650.57, this seems to be fixed. I don't know whether a Chrome  bug or a Stack Exchange bug got fixed, but it looks like this is now either [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or should be closed as no longer reproducible.