# "learn more" link beside tag name when modifying a question's tags does nothing in the latest version of Chrome

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags

This was a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) issue when raised previously through Chrome v30 Dev: ["Learn more" button on tags is broken in Chrome 30](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193736/learn-more-button-on-tags-is-broken-in-chrome-30), however now that Chrome v30 is no longer in dev/beta the issue is still present:

[image: Screenshot of link]

In the latest version of Chrome, if you click on this link the tag suggestions divider will close but nothing else will happen.

The link itself points to the tag wiki for the highlighted tag:

```html
<a href="/tags/{tag-name}/info" target="_blank">learn more</a>
```

If you give the tag suggestion area focus, however, the link then works as it should.